# Jumping animation in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I'm trying to put together a simple game in javascript, and I cant get the jumping to work:

```
function jump()
 {
     isJumping=true;

    var jumpint= setInterval(function() {
    ypos=ypos-5;
    }, 10);
    if(ypos==150)
    {
        isJumping == false;
        clearInterval(jumpint);
        jumpint = 0;
        alert("it works");
        return;

    }

 }
```

Whenever I call this function it provides the animation, and the character moves in the right direction, but it doesn't stop. Once the ypos would equal 150 it keeps moving and doesn't execute the if statement and I cant figure out why. Obviously, I'll some equation in there, but I want to get this jumping to execute right before I move on.

Comment: If you're developing a game with HTML5 and `<canvas>`, you may want to use `requestAnimationFrame` instead of `setInterval`. [Have a look](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.requestAnimationFrame).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the if-statement *inside* the `setInterval`, otherwise it will only be executed once.

```
var jumpint = setInterval(function() {
    ypos=ypos-5;
    if(ypos==150)
    {
        isJumping == false;
        clearInterval(jumpint);
        alert("it works");
    }
}, 10);
```

Also, you might want to change the condition to `ypos <= 150`. Say the `ypos` is 157. If you keep decreasing by 5, it will go 157 -> 152 -> 147 and jump right past the condition. To fix it, simply change the if-statement's condition to `ypos <= 150`.

Comment: @PeterJewicz If your question was correctly answered, don't forget to accept it (click the check mark).